# Spaces that are finitely covered by manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds, covering-spaces

Suppose $X \to Y$ is a finite-sheeted covering of CW-complexes. Moreover, assume that the total space is homotopy equivalent to a (closed, connected, smooth) manifold $M$. I am interested in conditions to impose on the map $X \to Y$ so that we can find a manifold $N \simeq Y$ and a covering $M \to N$ making the diagram $$ \begin{array}{ccc}
    X & \simeq & M \\
    \downarrow && \downarrow \\
    Y & \simeq & N
   \end{array}
$$
commute. In general, this is not possible, for example we could take any finite group $G$ and $$X = M \times EG \to M \times BG = Y.$$ Are there counterexamples for $Y$ a finite CW-complex? On the other side, are there conditions to impose so that we actually can deduce the existence of $N$?

Comment: If I remember correctly, there is a 3-dimensional compact (3D) Poincare duality complex with finite fundamental group not homotopy equivalent to a 3-dimensional manifold. The universal cover of this complex is homotopy-equivalent to $S^3$. This will provide a counter example. Check C. Thomas,  3-Manifolds and PD(3)-groups, an example might be there.

Comment: @Misha: I looked it up, it's in the appendix to a paper of Swan. http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970135?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=124895

Comment: @IanAgol: Good, so there is an example with $\pi_1(Y)\cong S_3$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conditions where $N$ exists are for example when $M$ is a non-positively curved locally symmetric manifold, by a theorem of Mostow (for hyperbolic manifolds) and Margulis in general. Mostow's theorem is generalized to manifolds with hyperbolic fundamental group whose [Gromov boundary is a sphere of dimension at least 5.](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1299766682)   So if one started with such a manifold, any group containing the fundamental group with finite index and torsion-free would have to be a manifold group.

More generally, it is conjectured that finitely presented groups which are $PD(n)$ groups are the fundamental groups of closed $n$-manifolds ([Conjecture 3.4](https://people.math.osu.edu/davis.12/pdgroup.pdf)). If true, this would show that $N$ exists when $X$ is aspherical. This conjecture would follow for $n\geq 5$ from the [Novikov conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novikov_conjecture). Many cases of this [conjecture are known](https://doi.org/10.1112/jtopol/jtm008) (for groups satisfying certain restrictions). See also [Sections 5 and 8 of this paper](http://www.ems-ph.org/doi/10.4171/077-1/4).

Comment: I am aware of Mostow's theorem which says that every homotopy equivalence of a hyperbolic manifold is homotopic to an isometry. But how exactly does that imply what I want? The analogue of Mostow's result for $S^1$ is obvious, but nevertheless I do not see how this implies that every finite complex that is finitely covered by some $X \simeq S^1$ has to be itself homotopy equivalent to $S^1$.

Comment: @JensReinhold: The point is that any homotopy equivalence of a hyperbolic manifold is homotopy equivalent to an isometry. If $M$ is hyperbolic, the finite-sheeted cover $X\to Y$ might not be regular, but we can pass to a finite cover so that $\tilde{X}\to Y$ is regular, and still homotopy equivalent to a hyperbolic manifold $\tilde{M}$. Then the covering translations of $\tilde{X}\to Y$ give homotopy equivalences of $\tilde{M}$, which in turn is realized by a finite group of isometries. The quotient is the desired manifold $N$.

Comment: Does this imply that any finite index subgroup of a hyperbolic group contains a finite index normal subgroup? If yes, is there some canonically defined one?

Comment: @Ian Agol: Thanks, that helped. But I still do not see where this uses that $Y$ is a finite complex. At some point this has to enter, as described in my question: Namely we have that $M \times BG$, for $G$ any finite group, is finitely covered by $M \times EG \simeq M$, but it is NOT homotopy equivalent to a manifold (not even homotopy equivalent to a finite complex).

Comment: @JensReinhold: The point is that since $Y$ (and X) are finite complexes, their fundamental groups are torsion-free. So the automorphisms of $\tilde{M}$ I described cannot have fixed points, hence $N$ is a manifold, not an orbifold. There are some details here, but I think that's where finiteness of Y is used.

Comment: Great, that makes sense! I feel enlightened - thanks.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: This is true more generally for a finite-index subgroup of a group. The group acts on cosets of a finite index subgroup as permutations. The kernel of this permutation action is a normal subgroup contained in the finite-index subgroup.

Comment: Yes, thanks. In other words this is also the intersection of all conjugate subgroups, of which there are finitely many. Probably this is actually largest normal subgroup contained in the subgroup.

Answer (score 10):

Indeed, C. Thomas, 3-Manifolds and PD(3)-groups, in "Novikov conjectures", Vol. 2, gives a reference to [Swan's example](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=124895). Namely, there is a finite complex $X$ which is a homotopy  3-sphere, a free $S_3$-action $S_3\times X\to X$, which cannot be realized (up to homotopy) as a free $S_3$-action on $S^3$, since $S_3$ cannot act freely on $S^3$ (the 3-sphere).